# Color Picker API change text color

Tags: jquery, html, css, color-picker

I am using the spectrum API and I cannot figure out how to just change basic text using the color picker tool. I can see that the basic example can return the hex value of a color but then how do I use that return value to change a text's color in HTML or CSS for that matter?

Here's the jsfiddle link of what I am trying to do

http://jsfiddle.net/ctkY3/4690/

//html

```
<h2>Basic Usage</h2>
<input type='text' class="basic"/>
<em id='basic-log'></em>

<h2>Full Example</h2>
<input type='text' id="full"/>


<p id="basic">
text basic
</p>

<p id="full">
text full
</p>
```

//CSS

```
.full-spectrum .sp-palette {
max-width: 200px;
}


#basic{

}

#full{

}
```

//JQuery

```
$(".basic").spectrum({
    color: "#f00",
    change: function(color) {
        $("#basic-log").text("change called: " + color.toHexString());
    }
});

$("#full").spectrum({
    color: "#ECC",
    showInput: true,
    className: "full-spectrum",
    showInitial: true,
    showPalette: true,
    showSelectionPalette: true,
    maxSelectionSize: 10,
    preferredFormat: "hex",
    localStorageKey: "spectrum.demo",
    move: function (color) {

    },
    show: function () {

    },
    beforeShow: function () {

    },
    hide: function () {

    },
    change: function() {

    },
    palette: [
        ["rgb(0, 0, 0)", "rgb(67, 67, 67)", "rgb(102, 102, 102)",
        "rgb(204, 204, 204)", "rgb(217, 217, 217)","rgb(255, 255, 255)"],
        ["rgb(152, 0, 0)", "rgb(255, 0, 0)", "rgb(255, 153, 0)", "rgb(255, 255, 0)", "rgb(0, 255, 0)",
        "rgb(0, 255, 255)", "rgb(74, 134, 232)", "rgb(0, 0, 255)", "rgb(153, 0, 255)", "rgb(255, 0, 255)"], 
        ["rgb(230, 184, 175)", "rgb(244, 204, 204)", "rgb(252, 229, 205)", "rgb(255, 242, 204)", "rgb(217, 234, 211)", 
        "rgb(208, 224, 227)", "rgb(201, 218, 248)", "rgb(207, 226, 243)", "rgb(217, 210, 233)", "rgb(234, 209, 220)", 
        "rgb(221, 126, 107)", "rgb(234, 153, 153)", "rgb(249, 203, 156)", "rgb(255, 229, 153)", "rgb(182, 215, 168)", 
        "rgb(162, 196, 201)", "rgb(164, 194, 244)", "rgb(159, 197, 232)", "rgb(180, 167, 214)", "rgb(213, 166, 189)", 
        "rgb(204, 65, 37)", "rgb(224, 102, 102)", "rgb(246, 178, 107)", "rgb(255, 217, 102)", "rgb(147, 196, 125)", 
        "rgb(118, 165, 175)", "rgb(109, 158, 235)", "rgb(111, 168, 220)", "rgb(142, 124, 195)", "rgb(194, 123, 160)",
        "rgb(166, 28, 0)", "rgb(204, 0, 0)", "rgb(230, 145, 56)", "rgb(241, 194, 50)", "rgb(106, 168, 79)",
        "rgb(69, 129, 142)", "rgb(60, 120, 216)", "rgb(61, 133, 198)", "rgb(103, 78, 167)", "rgb(166, 77, 121)",
        "rgb(91, 15, 0)", "rgb(102, 0, 0)", "rgb(120, 63, 4)", "rgb(127, 96, 0)", "rgb(39, 78, 19)", 
        "rgb(12, 52, 61)", "rgb(28, 69, 135)", "rgb(7, 55, 99)", "rgb(32, 18, 77)", "rgb(76, 17, 48)"]
    ]
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regular **DOM** way to do it : `document.getElementById("id").style.color = "#0f0f0f";`

Applied on your demo:

```
$(".basic").spectrum({
    color: "#f00",
    change: function(color) {
        $("#basic-log").text("change called: " + color.toHexString());
        document.getElementById("basic").style.color = color.toHexString();
    }
});
```

[**DOM fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/sxLwgrp6/3/)

The **jQuery** way to do it: `$(element).css('color', '#0f0f0f');`

Applied to your demo:

```
$(".basic").spectrum({
    color: "#f00",
    change: function(color) {
        $("#basic-log").text("change called: " + color.toHexString());
        $(basic).css('color', color.toHexString());
    }
});
```

[**jQuery fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/knhnwq0r/)

Comment: jsfiddle updated* now with both spectrums changing the text color;

Comment: Why not use jQuery as you are using it for everything else?